# How can I adjust column widths in Apache OpenOffice Writer?

Tags: libreoffice-writer, openoffice-writer

I have an Open Document Text (.odt) file in A4 landscape mode. One section of text is four columns (not a table, but textual columns). I want the first and last columns to be narrower, and the central two to be wider.

If I go to Format → columns, and tick the AutoWidth box, the columns come out as 2.45" each, with a 0.10" gap between them. If I adjust the first column down to 1.45", the second immediately goes up to 3.45", which is okay. However, if I then adjust the last down to 1.45", the first goes back up to 2.45". The numbers keep jumping around.

I did eventually manage to get this to work, but I’m not entirely sure how, and if I wanted to do it again I’d be no wiser on how to go about it. Is there a way to *stop* OpenOffice being so smart and automatically adjusting column width? I’d like to take control and adjust all the widths myself.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this with a current version of **LibreOffice Writer**. So, if switching to LibreOffice is an option for you, it would solve the issue without any further hassle. If it isn't, you may create a custom page style, thus "saving" the columns configuration for further use.

Comment: I have LibreOffice on another computer. I'll try that later today and report back.

Comment: Ooops - sorry, didn't catch all details of your question. I've tried to set the column widths manually using the ruler, this works with LO. When changing the Columns settings of the page style proerties, in fact modifying col 4 resets the width of col 1. So, the issue is still present in LO Writer 5.1.2.2. Please ignore my first comment.

Comment: Well, I couldn't find any other way to adjust widths in OpenOffice. In LibreOffice, I could click and drag, which is a perfectly viable workaround, so that did work for me.